# Domestic to international luggage allowance

Tags: luggage, international-travel

I have a SFO to Bangkok flight via LAX that was booked as one online. My first leg is SFO to LAX, so I have to check-in first on a domestic carrier, United Airlines.

I will be flying economy class. Official carrier is All-nippon airways except for the first leg, which is United Airlines.

Will my luggage will be charged based on domestic weight limits since I will be checking in on a domestic flight first onward to LAX? I am worried because I believe international travelers are allowed more than domestic passengers.

Comment: @Kris That answer doesn't apply to US originated flights

Comment: If the whole flight is international you will get the international luggage allowance for the whole trip.  However, it is not necessarily clear what airline's rules you will need to follow (including weight limits).  You really ought to ask the airline/

Comment: @dan1111 The rules of the first carrier (UA) apply for the whole trip

Comment: Since you are flying from the US, according to the DOT, your receipt must indicate your baggage allowance. What does it say?